# What is the difference between Mongo Scala Driver and Reactive-Mongo Driver in play framework?

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework

Hello I am new the play framework, and our team is planning to use mongodb. I found two drivers for it, [Mongo Scala Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver) and [Reactive-Mongo](http://reactivemongo.org/), they are both non-blocking and asynchronous.

What are the differences between them?

Comment: This is a valid question IMO, sorry that it got closed.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using the Play Framework, I highly recommend using the Play-ReactiveMongo driver which allows you to use Play's excellent JSON support (i.e. the [`JSObject` family](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJson)) instead of having to learn yet-another way of describing JSON objects: ReactiveMongo out of the box uses a similar-but-not-identical [`BSONValue`](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/api/index.html#reactivemongo.bson.BSONValue), `BSONDocument` etc.

Comment: While I enjoy the Play-JSON support in Play-ReactiveMongo, note that it does not always yield the most efficient BSON representation, e.g. Long values or dates can end up being represented as strings in the internal mongo storage instead of with the appropriate mongo datatype.

Comment: There is no case where a number is converted as BSON string by the Play JSON support, so if you get it as string in the DB, I suggest you double check.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. He didn't ask for a suggestion or an advertisement, he asked for a difference.

Answer (score -1):

If you use Play I think [ReactiveMongo](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo) will be comfortable, good documentation. many examples.I do not have exp. with another API instead ReactiveMongo) but from some editional information from [MongoDB doc -> Community](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/scala/) i think it is a good choice